# Is "--one-database" safe to use for importing from a dump?

Tags: mysql

If I make a full dump using `mysqldump --all-databases > dump.sql` and then I want to import just a single database, I can use `mysql --one-database db1 < dump.sql`.

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_one-database), This option is rudimentary and should be used with care because statement filtering is based only on USE statements.  Here is an example of how this could be dangerous:

`mysql --one-database db1`

```
DELETE FROM db2.t2;
USE db2;
DROP TABLE db1.t1;
CREATE TABLE db1.t1 (i INT);
USE db1;
INSERT INTO t1 (i) VALUES(1);
CREATE TABLE db2.t1 (j INT);
```

But this scenario seems very unlikely because I have never found a dump to contain statements that specify a *database.table* syntax.  So the question is, if I make a full dump as written above, is there any risk of using the --one-database option to restore?

Comment: "safe"??  Watch out for `DROP` statements in the dump.

Answer (score 0):

The only risk is time and missing out on trigger stored procedures.

Normally, mysqldumps are done in alphabetical order.

When loading a dump, expect databases `aardvark`, `alligator` and `antelope` to load early. Any database like `zoo` and `zebra` would require time because `--one-database` does not force a mysqldump to load the specified database. The entire dump must be read until the specified database is in use.

For example, `mysql --one-database zebra` will read the entire mysqldump but start loading when it gets to the line the dump that says

```
USE zebra
```

Then, all `INSERT INTO` commands are processed until the EOF or until it see another line like

```
USE zimbabwe
```

Some developers I know would wait until the database they chose is loaded. Then, hit Ctrl-C. I would not risk that. You should make sure that all triggers and stored procedures are loaded as well.

If you cannot wait and want to Ctrl-C, login to mysql while the dump is still loading and make sure all tables, views, triggers, and stored procedures have been loaded.